# Illustrator CS6 saving as CS5 by default?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, image-format

I don't really use Illustrator, but as the techy I am I help someone who does use it regularly - not a techy at all.

The problem is I've installed her CS6 because of the 64 bit support, but she has to deliver those files to people who still uses CS5. So it's started to be a problem for her to remember changing format to CS5 when saving the file.

Is there any way I can make CS5 the default saving format in Illustrator?

Switching back to CS5 is an option, but if I can avoid loosing the 64 bits capability, I'll be glad.

Answer (score 2):

create an action in which you include the step of saving for cs5

Comment: Not a bad idea. Since the default behavior cannot be changed, this could be a possible work-around if you're willing to modify your work flow

Comment: Sorry, I really don't use Illustrator usually. Could you give me some more idea/indications to achieve this? A good link can be a valid response, as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no.

All Illustrator versions save to their own version by default. There is no way to Save or Save As to a legacy version by default.